# Can't add multiple rows in a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to put multiple family member details in database 
but the insert isn't working and it doesn't display any error.

I already tried to do: `<input type="text" name="family_member_first_name[]" class="form-control"/>` but it didn't work.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit4"])) {
    if ($_SESSION['email']) {
        $db->where('primary_email', $_SESSION['email']);
        $email_fetch_femily = $db->getone('om_user_list_a');
        if ($email_fetch_femily) {
            $fetch_id_family = $email_fetch_femily['id'];
        }

        $status = 1;
        $c_by   = 1;
        $c_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $c_ip   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $row = $_POST['num'];

        for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
            $insert_family_details = $mysqli->query("INSERT into `om_relative_list` (`user_id`,`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`,`birth_date`,`relative_type`,`marital_status`,`education_status`,`occupation`,`phone`,`gratuity_ratio`,`nomination_ratio`,`status`,`created_by`,`created_date`,`created_ip`) values ('$fetch_id_family','" . $_POST['family_member_first_name'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_middle_name'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_last_name'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_birth_date'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_relation'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_merital_status'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_education'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_occupation'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_phone'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_gratuity_ratio'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['family_member_nomination_ratio'][$i] . "','$status','$c_by','$c_date','$c_ip')");
        }

        if ($insert_family_details) {
            echo "<script>alert('family details insert successfully');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('!!!!family deatis insert unsuccessfully');</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><font size="2">HOW MANY MEMBER IN YOUR FAMILY ?</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" name="family_member_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" style="padding:11pt;width:200px;"/>
        <span><b><font size="2">SUBMIT</font></b></span></button>
    </div>
</div><br><br>
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $family_member; $i++) {
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $family_member;?>" name="num">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><font size="2">First Name</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_first_name[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default ">
            <label><font size="2">Middle Name</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_middle_name[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default ">
            <label><font size="2">Last name</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_last_name[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default ">
            <label><font size="2">birthdate</font></label>
            <input id="datepicker3" class="form-control" name="family_member_birth_date[]" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-selectFx">
            <label><font size="2">Realation</font></label>
            <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide cs-transparent form-control" name="family_member_relation[]" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
    $db->where('type_id','4');
                $Industry = $db->get('om_master_values');
                foreach ($Industry as $indu) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php=$indu['id']?>"><?php=$indu['master_values']?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default  form-group-default-selectFx">
            <label><font size="2">MARITAL STATUS</font></label>
            <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide cs-transparent form-control" name="family_member_merital_status[]" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="married">MARRIED</option>
                <option value="unmarried">UNMARRIED</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-selectFx">
            <label><font size="2">EDUCATION</font></label>
            <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide cs-transparent form-control" name="family_member_education[]" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
    $db->where('type_id','5');
                $Industry = $db->get('om_master_values');
                foreach($Industry as $indu){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $indu['id'] ?>"><?php echo $indu['master_values'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><font size="2">occupation</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_occupation[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><font size="2">PHONE</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_phone[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><font size="2">gratuity_ratio</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_gratuity_ratio[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><font size="2">nomination_ratio</font></label>
            <input type="text" name="family_member_nomination_ratio[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me with this and give me updated code.

Comment: Post your Html View @Dharmesh Makwana

Comment: $_POST['num'] Means Number of Records. Is Correct

Comment: echo your `$row` and see what is the result

Comment: Don't put your codes in commen. Edit question and add code there

Comment: i edit my question and html code is there in my question

Comment: is there any one......help me for this task

Comment: any one there ......